# How to show a hitting time is finite almost surely?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

A one-dimensional symmetric simple random walk starts at $S_0 = 1$. How to show with probability one it passes $x = 0$ (or I guess equivalently, the stopping time of hitting $x = 0$ at the first time is finite almost surely)?

It's just a new-learner's doubt, not a homework problem, I would appreciate any advise.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

We have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{S_n\leqslant 0\}\right) &= \mathbb P\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{S_n\leqslant 0\mid X_1=-1\}\right)\mathbb P(X_1=-1)\\ &\quad+ \mathbb P\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{S_n\leqslant 0\mid X_1=1\}\right)\mathbb P(X_1=1)\\
&= \mathbb P(X_1=-1) + \mathbb P\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{S_n\leqslant -1\}\right)\mathbb P(X_1=1)\\
&= \frac12 + \frac12\mathbb P\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{S_n\leqslant 0\}\right)^2,
\end{align}
from which it follows that
$$ \mathbb P\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{S_n\leqslant 0\}\right)=1.$$

Comment: @Stupid_Guy Does this answer your question?